# How to add new table rows and columns with table headers to CSS table

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, css-tables

I have the following table format and would like to be able to add new columns and new rows based on user inputs.

The clickable part of the document basically consists of a list of names that will be the far left item of each row.  Additionally there is a second clickable area that should add elements horizontally to each row adding a table header as it adds a new column.

For example:

List of names:
[Jeff] [bill] [fred] [jake]

List of items to be added to each column:
[apples] [oranges] [cars] [shoes]

If Jeff and bill were selected and apples and oranges were selected the table should be updated to look as such.

```
[Name] [apples] [oranges]
[jeff] [      ] [       ]
[bill] [      ] [       ]
```

If then another item was selected it would look as such

```
[Name] [apples] [oranges] [shoes]
[jeff] [      ] [       ] [     ]
[bill] [      ] [       ] [     ]
```

Additionally if another name was selected at this point it should look as such

```
[Name] [apples] [oranges] [shoes]
[jeff] [      ] [       ] [     ]
[bill] [      ] [       ] [     ]
[fred] [      ] [       ] [     ]
```

This is what the html structure looks like:

```
<form>
    <div id="opTable"> 
        <div class="thead">
            <div class="th first">
                Name
            </div>
            <div class="th">
                clase
            </div>
            <div class="th">
                gold
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tbody"> 
            <div class="tr"> 
                <div class="td first">
                    Billy
                </div>
                <div class="td">
                    <input type="text" style="width:100px"/>
                </div>
                <div class="td">
                    <input type="text" style="width:100px"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Additionally, the code should be able to remove a name and or item in the same ways.  I hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to display clearly is a table, then I would suggest to also use a `table` for the markup.

This will also make rendering the markup as a table a lot easier :) By using a `table`, displaying the columns next to each other will be an inherent feature. No CSS trickery needed.

Adding another row will become (I use DOM API here because it's more performant than appending strings if your table gets large)

```
//Assuming each row has the same nr of columns
var numcols = $('#opTable tr:eq(0) td').length;
var row = document.createElement('tr');

//Insert name
var name_td = document.createElement('td');
row.appendChild(name_td);
name_td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));

//fill the rest with empty td's
for (var i=1; i < numcols; i++) {
    row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
}

$('#opTable').append(row);
```

Adding a column means doing something very similar, the difference is just that you append a `<td>` to each `<tr>`:

```
$('#opTable').find('tr').each(function(i) {
    if (i == 0) {
       $(this).append('<td>' + item + '</td>');  
    }
    else {
        $(this).append('<td/>');
    }
});
```

Comment: I am doing an experament using css properties to define tables. This is why I have specified css tables in the question.  I apreciate your answer and will see if I can make its concepts fit my project, but I fear the issue will come in the form of not including the columns in the new row.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to have the columns already exist and just hide them by default making a click on the item unhide its column.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, `.append()` and/or `.appendTo()` are the functions you'll want to use. Combine that with an `.each()` loop and you should be good to go.

Comment: I am having a bit of difficulty understanding how this works.  I apologize, I am not very strong with javascript and am considering just generating the tables in php.  I wanted to reduce the amount of code by trying this with javascript.  Is there any way you can give an example of how this solution would apply to my question?

Comment: Sorry, but you haven't provided any JavaScript code to be fixed, but instead ask for a complete solution. With this much creative work, I start billing hours.

Comment: `$('#opTable div.thead:first ').append("<div class='th'>header</div>");    
            $('#opTable div.tr').each(function(){
                $(this).append("<div class='td'><input type='text' /></div>");
            });` Is the code I was able to come up with to create a new column, but I cant for the life of me figure out how to add a new row and keep all the same columns that exist in the previous row.

Comment: For adding a new row, you'll want to use `.after()` or `before()`.

Comment: I guess the question would then be, what is the seelector of the last item in which I am to place a new row after.

Comment: Select the entire row: `$('div.tr:eq(0)')` for the first row, `eq(1)` for the second, etc.